# Is there a way i could use an audio api like pydub with discord.py?

Tags: python, audio, discord.py, pydub

I'm trying to make a discord bot that could do simple commands like looping an mp3 seamlessly and adding stems on top of each other, like in a DAW. I want to do all this using pydub and play the audio through the discord vc, is it possible?

Comment: Use discordutils library

Comment: @DjWalkzz do I use discordutils along with pydub, or does it do everything i described?

Comment: it does everything